# not able to capture telerik vuejs daterangepicker change event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm confused on how to capture the daterange event properly. The goal is to fire another event when the date range is changed (start and end dates are selected). But during debugging, it seems like the daterangepricker change event is fired when the start *OR* the end date is changed....it's hard to captured the "complete" change event because the change event is triggered when one of the dates is changed...so the state of the date range isn't isolated atomically (after start and end date are selected).

Observe the console.log output in the stackblitz during a date range change, it should be clearly depicted.

The expected behavior of the daterangepicker is that the change event wouldn't  fired until the "range" event is completed - the start and end dates are selected.

To reproduce...select 20116-01-01 and try to forward through the dates to 2016-12-31....you can't (I mean you can but the start date is lost), when you start cycling through the months it resets the dates so they end up being "null".

The stackblitz (awesome by the way) is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mrcw3c

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to get the dates when the range is updated. Or the user experience of the widget?

Comment: Exactly. Behavior of the widget is terrible - it's even firing multiple same events. You can work around it or you can go and tell Telerik to fix it....